# Показ иконок в меню и ActionBar в AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, actionbar, menu, icon, android-menu

Пытаюсь использовать [Material Icons](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) в меню буквенной игры -

[image: игра]

Скачал понравившиеся PNG-файлы -

[image: иконки]

И добавил их в оба меню-файла мобильного приложения -

**menu_main.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

**menu_game.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_swap"
        android:orderInCategory="20"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_swap_vert_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_swap"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_shuffle"
        android:orderInCategory="40"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_swap_horiz_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_shuffle"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_recall"
        android:orderInCategory="60"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_undo_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_recall"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_turn"
        android:orderInCategory="80"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_turn"/>

</menu>
```

Но увы - "не горит волшебный фонарь" и иконок все равно не видно.

Добавлением `android:showAsAction="always"` или `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` проблема также не лечится.

Прошу помочь советом с учетом важного для меня условия - моя игра использует `AppCompatActivity` с фрагментами и `minSdkVersion=“8”`.

Также прошу не предлагать устаревшие библиотеки вроде `ActionBarSherlock`, а наоборот - порекомендовать современное (для 2015 года) решение проблемы показа иконок вместо текста в меню и Action Bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените `android:showAsAction` на `app:showAsAction`, xmlns:app у вас уже прописан.
При использовании AppCompat нужно использовать другое пространство имен для атрибутов *showAsAction*, *actionViewClass*, *actionProviderClass*, так как их не было в старых версиях android (до версии 3.0).

Это описано в [руководстве по action bar.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Toolbar(если вы этого не делаете) вместо ActionBar. У него шире возможности, можно самому внутри рисовать кнопки и использовать их. Toolbar прописывается в основном layout файле Activity. И не обязательно пункты меню прописывать в файле menu_game.xml.
Пример:

[image: Код]
<sub>(источник: [101apps.co.za](https://www.101apps.co.za/images/android/articles/Toolbar/toolbarWidget1.png))</sub>

Comment: Хороший совет, перейду на Toolbar - спасибо (я нажал +1)

Answer (score 0):

Буквально вчера была похожая проблема. Попробуйте что то вроде этого:
В тег menu нужно добавить

```
xmlns:com.example.app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

и в item

```
com.example.app:showAsAction="always"
```

Вместо com.example.app вставить свое.