# Android не показывает элементы меню в actionbar

Tags: android, actionbar, android-menu

Я решил добавить в приложение небольшой редактор. Кнопку сохранить решил поместить её в **ActionBar**.

Добавил **меню** со следующей разметкой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:title="@string/save"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />
</menu>
```

В код Activity добавил:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_wordedit, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_save:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

После запуска получается:
[image: Вид ActionBar на эмуляторе Android]

Почему элемент скрыт под кнопкой меню, а не виден сразу?

Comment: [это решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435244/177345) ? Если оно подходит, то на него закроем ваш вопрос

Comment: @pavlofff Это. В первый раз пробывал не получалось. Со второго раза получилось. Нужно было в XML указать, что такое APP